# How to do version numbers?

Tags: version, product

My company is building a product. It's going to be versioned by SVN. It's a webapp so basically there will never be a version out which doesn't have some features in them and thus could always be labeled as beta. But since it's going to be a corporate product I really don't want the "unstable watchout" on there. So how would you go about versioning? Is 1.0 stable? Should the build date be in the version number? Tell me what you guys think!

Comment: After some time, when you reach ~6 or 7 you should switch to 2010 (or whatever nice year) ;)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx in Remarks

Comment: After going on with dates for a couple of years, switch back to numbers, but include buzzwords like _HD_, _FullHD_, _4K_, _Gluten-free_, whatever's cool right now. So people outside the software industry can relate.

Comment: Don't forget to NEVER include new features in upcoming versions. There is always a market for DLCs. Oh and make a version exclusively for women that has a red skin, and one for women who are left-handed that has a slightly more orange skin

Answer (score 270, accepted):

[**major**].[**minor**].[**release**].[**build**]

**major**: Really a marketing decision. Are you ready to call the version 1.0? Does the company consider this a major version for which customers might have to pay more, or is it an update of the current major version which may be free? Less of an R&D decision and more a product decision.

**minor**: Starts from 0 whenever **major** is incremented. +1 for every version that goes public.

**release**: Every time you hit a development milestone and release the product, even internally (e.g. to QA), increment this. This is especially important for communication between teams in the organization. Needless to say, never release the same 'release' twice (even internally). Reset to 0 upon minor++ or major++.

**build**: Can be a SVN revision, I find that works best.

**Examples**
My current chrome: 83.0.4103.61

Comment: This almost matches my definition of versioning my software. However I reset the release to 0 as soon as I increase the "minor" version number.

Comment: What for minor if you use git?

Comment: @Brain: Have a look at `git describe`

Comment: @Assaf Lavie What's SVN?

Comment: @Daenyth I tried typing in that command, and this is what I've got `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` What about it?

Answer (score 74):

x.y.z.g

increments in g are unstable. (or RCs) 
increments in z are stable and mean bug fixes.
increments in y are stable and mean new features.
increments in x are stable, major release without 100% backward compatibility.

Comment: is this your way or a common usage ?

Comment: About the G spot I am not sure, the rest is common.

Comment: Good versioning scheme for components. But for a commercial product, everything beyond x.y is just confusing the customer and making communication difficult IMHO. Especially web apps, which require the customer to migrate - "release early, release often" doesn't cut it there...

Comment: For customers, there is only x.y or just X (same as MS).

Comment: But it would still be good for debugging if its something that the customer actually install/purchase to have the full version hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 34):

I once wrote an elaborate "versioning style guide" for a large project of mine. The project failed to materialize, but the style guide is [still available online](http://rootdirectory.de/wiki/VersioningStyleGuide). It's my personal opinion, perhaps it is helpful (or inspirational) to you.

Beware, it's a long text, and goes into component versioning vs. product versioning and stuff like that. It also expresses strong opinions on some versioning schemes popular in the OSS community, but I have them, so I express them. ;-)

I disagree with using the Subversion revision number, for example. You might want to maintain a released version while continuing development in TRUNK, so you'll set up a maintenance branch - and your revision number versioning goes down the drain.

**Edit:** As a summary, it distinguishes between versioning source files, components, and the overall product. It uses a system of seperate x.y versoning for components and the product, with a nice interdependency between the two that makes tracing which component version belongs to which product version trivial. It also talks about how to handle alpha / beta / release / patch cycles without breaking the system. Actually, it's a modus operandi for the whole development cycle, so you might want to cherry-pick. ;-)

**Edit 2:** As enough people found my article useful to make this a "Nice Answer", I started working on the article again. PDF and LaTeX versions are now available, a complete rewrite including better language and explanatory graphics will follow as soon as I can find the time. Thank you for your votes!

Comment: this link seems broken now. Can it be shared again?

Comment: @AaronSt.Clair Works here. The server is local and shared through DDNS, so minor downtimes can happen. If the link seems dead just try again a little bit later.

Answer (score 31):

Get yourself some inspiration from Wikipedia: ["Software versioning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning)

Another "new" and "relatively popular" option is [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)

**Summary:**

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as
>   extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

Comment: @iconiK - If you use SO, you surely understand that "Here's a clear, concise answer on the same page with other answers" is more helpful than "here's a link to a different site where you can dig through old versions of an article and maybe find something relevant."

Answer (score 11):

**a.b.c.d**

Increments : when 
 - **d**: bug fixes 
 - **c**: maintenance, e.g. performance improvement 
 - **b**: new features
 - **a**: architecture change

The mandatory is the most left one e.g. if there are for example a new feature and a bug fixed then you only have to increment **b**.

Comment: What are some examples of an architectural change?

Comment: For example a progressive migration to microservices or a migration to another platform that involves dramatic changes over base code,

Answer (score 9):

Based on my experience with complex enterprise platform level dependency management and release versioning I've come to recommend an approach I like to call **Semi-Semantic Versioning**.

Basically it builds off of [Semantic Versioning 2.0](http://semver.org) but is not quite as strict.

Semi-Semantic Version Segments:

```
<primary.release.segment>[-<pre.release.segment>][+<post.release.segment>]
```

Primary Release Segment Format:

> MARKETTING.MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

Each segment should allow alphanumerics, but pure numerics are recommended for logical incremental changes.

Like SemVer, I recommend **Major, Minor, and Patch components** to represent reverse compatibility tiers, but I also recommend prepending a **Marketing component**. This allows product owners, feature epics/groups, and business concerns to bump the primary component independent of technical compatibility concerns.

Unlike other answers, I don't recommended appending a Build number to the primary segment. Instead, add a **Post-Release Segment** following a '+' (ex: 1.1.0.0+build.42). SemVer calls this build metadata, but I think Post-Release Segment is clearer. This segment is great for declaring the suffix data as not related to the compatibility info in the primary **Release Segment**. Your continuous integration builds can then be given the previous release number appended with an incremental build number that resets after each primary release (ex: 1.1.0.0 -> 1.1.0.0+build.1 -> 1.1.0.0+build.2 -> 1.1.0.1 ). Some people alternately like to put the svn revision number here or the git commit sha to make it easy to tie to the code repository. Another option is to use the post-release segment for hotfixes and patches, tho it might be worth considering adding a new primary release component for that. It can always get dropped when the patch component is incremented, since the versions are effectively left-aligned and sorted.

In addition to the release and post-release segments, people often want to use a **Pre-Release Segment** to indicate almost-stable pre-releases like alphas, betas and release candidates. The SemVer approach to this works well, but I recommend separating numerical components from alpha-numeric classifiers (ex: 1.2.0.0+alpha.2 or 1.2.0.0+RC.2). Normally you would bump the release segment at the same time as adding the post-release segment and then drop the pre-release segment when you next bump them primary release segment (ex: 1.0.1.2 -> 1.2.0.0-RC.1 -> 1.2.0.0). Pre-release segments get added to indicate that the release version is coming up, usually just a fixed set of features for more in-depth testing and sharing that doesn't change minute to minute based on more commits.

**The beauty of having all of this semantically defined in a way that covers almost all use-cases is that you can parse, sort, compare and increment them in a standard way.** This is especially important when using CI systems for complex applications with lots of small independently versioned components (like micro-services) each with their own managed dependencies.

If you're interested, I wrote [a semi-semantic parser in ruby](https://github.com/pivotal-cf-experimental/semi_semantic). I needed to not just use this pattern but be able to manage other apps that used it.

Answer (score 4):

"Version numbers" are a matter for your internal version control system.  Release numbers are a different matter (and should be KEPT different).

Stick to a simple MAJOR.MINOR release system (like v1.27), where MAJOR is the compatibility level (version 2.x is incompatible with or at least majorly different from version 1.x) and MINOR is your bugfix releases or minor enhancements.  As long as you follow the X.Y format, you can also use other systems like YEAR.MONTH (2009.12) or YEAR.RELEASE (2009.3).  But really you're probably best sticking to MAJOR.MINOR unless you have a good reason not to.

Definitely don't use anything that doesn't fit the X.Y format, as it'll make it tough for distros, announcement websites, etc. to work with you, and that alone could seriously affect your project's popularity.

Use branches and tags in your (preferably distributed) version control system to mark specific internal version numbers as relating to MAJORS and MINORS respectively.

And yes, 1.0 should be stable.  All releases should be stable, unless they're marked alpha, beta, or RC.  Use Alphas for known-broken-and-incomplete.  Betas for known-broken.  RCs for "try it; you'll probably spot things we missed".  Anything without one of these should (ideally, of course) be tested, known good, have an up to date manual, etc.

Comment: I agree what the user sees and what you build are two different things, but don't you have to link the two somehow? i.e. your release and version numbers should be related and you should be able to discover a version number form a release number

Comment: With open source, we don't care about build numbers. We distribute source code, and builds are up to the distros. If they see a bug in their version, but not in the source release, then they did something wrong in the build. Otherwise, it's the code for that release tag. Tags are visible in VC too.

Answer (score 3):

Version scheme: [major].[minor].[devrel][mark]

[major]: increment if you have a drastic change in development.
[minor]: increment if you have a minor change in development.
[devrel]: increment if you have a bug fix. Reset to zero if major++ or minor++.
[mark]: a, b or rc: a is an alpha release, b is beta release, and rc is a release candidate. Note that versions like 1.3.57a or 1.3.57b or 1.3.57rc is before the version 1.3.57. Start at 0.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in SVN then why not use the SVN revision number?

If you look at the bottom right of this web page you'll see the Stack Overflow version number which is the SVN revision number.

Comment: See my answer - SVN revision number breaks once you set up a maintenance branch.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty popular these days to just use the Subversion revision number.

Comment: See my answer - SVN revision number breaks once you set up a maintenance branch.

Comment: Using the SVN revision as PART of your version number is very common/popular.  Using only the SVN revision number has plenty of problems, such as what DevSolar points out.

Answer (score 2):

Versioning is up to you; I'd put 1.0 on the first version I was confident in.  You may want to follow it up quickly with other versions, since some software vendors have given 1.0 a bad reputation.

You do want some way of tying the version number to the exact build used, but you probably want it to be nice and simple for your end users.  Consider using standard version numbers, and tagging the SVN repository with the version number included.

Answer (score 2):

While just going with the Subversion revision number is nice and simple, it does remove information from the version number. Users might consider this a bad thing.

I assume that your webapp will have some kind of deployment procedure, so that not each revision in Subversion is actually published. Since it is impossible from the "outside" (from the user's perspective) to determine when releases are being made, and how many revisions the code will undergo between them, it makes the numbers almost random. They will be increasing, and I guess it's possible to surmise *some* kind of distance from comparing two revisions, but not much.

Classical version numbers tend to "dramatize" releases, so that users can build some kind of expectation. It is easier to think "I have version 1.0, now version 1.1 is out adding this and that, that sounds interesting" than to think "yesterday we ran SO revision 2587, today it's 3233, it must be lots better!".

Of course, this dramatization can be inflated too, with companies picking version numbers that are meant to sound more interesting than is motivated by the actual differences in the product, I guess going with the revision number counters this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

We've spent way too much time deciding when to increment the major version. Some shops would rarely do it so you would have releases like 1.25.3 and others would do it for ever release giving you 15.0

I got fed up with that and convinced everyone the major release number is just the year and the minor is just a sequential release within the year. The users seemed to like it and it's a no-brainer to come-up with the next version number.

Year.Release.build

- year = current year
- release = sequence # of public releases with
  new functionality - reset to 1 every
  year
- build = incremented for bug
  fixes and internal releases

EDIT

** Now this was for an internal app that was continually enhanced **

This would probably not work for commercial apps where it's important to have major releases at different times of the year for marketing and financial purposes.

Comment: ...which makes the first release of a new year a "major release" automatically, no matter how significant the changes. *And* you cannot do a "major" release *within* the year, either...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this question exists is because we don't have a single agreed upon way to do configuration management.

The way I like to do version number is just increment integer from 1.  I don't want a multi part version number that I will have to explain or document.  And I don't want to use SVN rev number as that will require some explaining as well.

You would need some release scripts on top of SVN to make this happen

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience in the area. However, here's what I'd do:

1. Choose a scheme for numbering revisions and stick to it. Be consistent.
2. Each version change should represent *a significant change*. How small a change is significant and the levels of change that are reflected in the version number are up to you.

Of course, you can just use the svn revision number --- like many others have suggested!!!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use a simple major.minor.julian_date syntax.

Where;

- major - First release is 1 and then when we introduce major new features or changes so significant they are not backwards compatible increase this number.
- minor - The major milestone releases. For each build pushed by production this number increases.
- julian_date - The [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) the build was pushed to QA.

Example of the first release pushed to QA on 1/15 is -> 1.0.015 
Example of the first release pushed to Production on 3/4 is -> 1.1.063

It's not perfect, but handy as we push builds to QA near daily.

Answer (score 0):

Some good info here:

[When to Change File/Assembly Versions](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57148.aspx)

First of all, file versions and assembly versions need not coincide with each other. I recommend that file versions change with each build. But, don’t change assembly versions with each build just so that you can tell the difference between two versions of the same file; use the file version for that. Deciding when to change assembly versions takes some discussion of the types of builds to consider: shipping and non-shipping.

Non-Shipping Builds 
In general, I recommend keeping non-shipping assembly versions the same between shipping builds. This avoids strongly-named assembly loading problems due to version mismatches. Some people prefer using publisher policy to redirect new assembly versions for each build. I recommend against that for non-shipping builds, however: it doesn’t avoid all of the loading problems. For example, if a partner x-copies your app, they may not know to install publisher policy. Then, your app will be broken for them, even though it works just fine on your machine.

But, if there are cases where different applications on the same machine need to bind to different versions of your assembly, I recommend giving those builds different assembly versions so that the correct one for each app can be used without having to use LoadFrom/etc.

Shipping Builds 
As for whether it’s a good idea to change that version for shipping builds, it depends on how you want the binding to work for end-users. Do you want these builds to be side-by-side or in-place? Are there many changes between the two builds? Are they going to break some customers? Do you care that it breaks them (or do you want to force users to use your important updates)? If yes, you should consider incrementing the assembly version. But, then again, consider that doing that too many times can litter the user’s disk with outdated assemblies.

When You Change Your Assembly Versions 
To change hardcoded versions to the new one, I recommend setting a variable to the version in a header file and replacing the hardcoding in sources with the variable. Then, run a pre-processor during the build to put in the correct version. I recommend changing versions right after shipping, not right before, so that there's more time to catch bugs due to the change.

Answer (score -3):

Or to use your 'thought' version number comma subversion number..
z.B.:

1.0.101 // revision 101, release

or 1.0.101-090303 // with release date, i use this