# Incorporate Team Coherence version label into build

Tags: delphi, version-control, version

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers) suggests using an SVN revision number as part of the version number when building a release. I want to do something similar using Team Coherence, which doesn't do revision numbers quite the same way.

For Delphi 2009 how can I set up a build script so that every release automatically includes a number or tag linking it to a specific Team Coherence check-in or version label? Just a way to access the current version label would be great, though a solution that automatically updates it would be even better.

Comment: Erika - did you get a reply from Ewan? Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Actually I did get a response-- there are command line tools for TC and apparently those can do it. But then this whole project became low priority, so I didn't get a chance to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this (though I'm interested in the answer, I use TC myself) - but have you emailed Ewan at QSC about it? On the few occasions I've needed some help doing something like this he's replied very quickly and if he doesn't know how to do it, well quite honestly you probably can't - he's the TC developer! :-)

support@teamcoherence.com

[QSC web site](http://www.teamcoherence.com/default.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try contacting him.