# Java library version after methods return type update

Tags: java, version, versioning

I've modified a Java library changing some methods return type from his primitive to his equivalent class (for example from int to Integer, from float to Float). There are no other changes in the library.

In normal use the change should not alter the library behaviour because Java automatically unbox the values. Otherwise if the returned value is null an exception will be thrown by the JVM (currently the library throws an exception for an error during a parsing phase).

Given that the current version is 1.0.1, should I release the new library as 1.1.0 or 2.0.0?

Comment: Is there any kind of processes or guidelines in place for versioning? For us, a change like that would go to 1.0.2.  The last thing you would want to do is start jumping the version around breaking any existing consistency.

Comment: No, there is no process or guideline, it is a library where I work in spare time. I'm agree with your comment, I want avoid to increase the version number too much with no reason.

Comment: Well based on your two choices then, I would go 1.1.0 as the change seems pretty minor.  Found this, might be useful...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864448/best-practice-software-versioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864448/best-practice-software-versioning)

Answer (score 1):

From the book [*Practical API Design - Confessions of a Java Framework Architect*](http://www.apress.com/9781430209737/).

> If a method claims to return a non-null value in one version, then changing it to return
>   `null` is in fact an incompatible change, because this change can be **observed** from the outside and negatively **influences** the component's users.

In another way in the book [*Enterprise Software Architecture and Design Entities, Services, and Resources*](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470565454.html):

> Typically, version identifiers include major and minor version numbers, with the expectation that **minor version updates** are **backward compatible** with earlier versions with the **same major version** number.

And in the [*Software versioning - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning):

> In principle, in subsequent releases, the *major* number is increased when there are significant jumps in functionality, the *minor* number is incremented when only minor features or significant fixes have been added, and the *revision* number is incremented when minor bugs are fixed.

[image]

Comment: So you're suggesting to go for 2.0.0?

Comment: But my change is not strictly backward compatible because of possibly null returned value.

Comment: Since you already have the versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1, the next version will obviously be 1.0.2