# Naming convention for android apps?

Tags: android, version, naming-conventions

I've searched through stackoverflow and this doesn't seem to be a duplicate question, so please notify me if it has already been asked. I've made a second version of an app and I was wondering if there was a naming convention for the app versions. In my gradle, I've changed the values of versionCode and versionName to

```
versionCode 2
versionName "1.0.2"
```

Is this the right convention? Is there even a convention? Does versionCode have to be an integer? Is 1.02 or 1.0.02 acceptable? And does it have to be by increments of 1(i.e. can I jump straight to 1.7 on the second update)?(sorry for all the questions, I wanted to get all of it at once.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`versionCode` have to be integer, and it is used for android to keep track of which apk is latest, e.g. in Google Play, you can upload your apk if your new apk has versionCode larger than that of the apk you previously uploaded.

`versionName` is for display only, and communication with user, it is up to you to define it. I.e. no restriction

Comment: For versionCode, does it have to increment by 1? Can i go from 1 to 3?

Comment: it is fine to go from 1 to 3, as long as you increase it

Comment: actually you don't need to increase it that often in development, only update it when you are going to deploy

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just curious. I plan on going from 1 to 2 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There are no literal restrictions on either, just their data types:
`versionCode` can be any integer and `versionName` can be any string.

**However,** Android uses the `versionCode` to tell which builds are more recent - and doesn't let users install an apk if the `versionCode` of the apk to install is less than the `versionCode` of the apk already installed.

**Therefore version code changes should always be to larger numbers** - though the how much larger is technically irrelevant.

`versionName` is for display purposes only. It could be set to `"v1.43 - blueVersion attempt4"`.

A [common naming conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864448/best-practice-software-versioning) is to label each release version major.minor.fix in the version name, and then reflect it in the version code. e.g. v "2.3.11" becomes version code 20311. which could be followed by v"3.0.0" = code 30000.