# Versioning "Rules" (Assembly/File) Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, versioning

I have a question regarding assembly/file versioning in Class Library project in Visual Studio (C#).

We have 4 numbers (example: 1.0.0.0) and according to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

The four numbers are in this format:

> [major version].[minor version].[build number].[revision]

My question is, how exactly do we determine "Major", "Minor", "Build Number", and "Revision"? Are "Major" and "Minor" more subjective while "Build Number" and "Revision" more objective (as we can actually count them)?

Are there any actual "rules" regarding that?

I am rather confused because according to this thread:
[Best Practice: Software Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864448/best-practice-software-versioning)

basically it is a matter of preference. Can anybody clarify or having proper "rules" (with example will be best) regarding this?

Comment: It is a matter of preference and hence this question should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: If you are the single programmer it is entirely up to you how to version your files. In the end these versions are just a help for you to determine what you actually have to debug when a problem arises...

Comment: did you try to use the [UploadFromStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.uploadfromstream.aspx) method ? I've faced the same problem and this solve my problem

Comment: @Thomas: No, I have never used it. Seems like this is for Azure project? What I am looking for is rather more formal definition of the versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
I kind of partially get the answer:
[How to do version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers)

Seems like this explains best so far. Thanks!