# How to choose software version number?

Tags: version

I plan to attribute a version number to my software. This number will help me to track the evolution and possible issue of each version.

I often see software with different version like v3.1.5 or v5.3.1. Is there a standard for attributing such number or it depend of the developer?

Even if I'm just a hobbyiste I want to learn and makes things right.

Feel free to add Tags for question tracking. I have no idea of which one I should use.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2864448/1271037

Answer (score 0):

It's all on the developer and project management. Typically before 1 is pre-release.

Whatever you define as a deliverable product would be 1. If you have a release schedule or planned features that you would call a 2.0, then the scale building up to that release would be 1.x.

There's no set: 2.0 has to be twice the product as 1.0. It's just that you remain consistent with measurable goals. If you have 1.0 and you want to implement a user forum feature by 2.0. Then maybe a working user registration and profile would be a 1.5. Improving on bugs related to user registration might be 1.5.1.

If it's a less formal project management style you are following, you can increment however you want. But consistency is key.